# To announce the lowest price to win a project

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Please imagine there is a big competition between two huge companies to win a national project. Each one is going to announce a lower price the employer to achieve that amazing project. I have not  the idea what is the business term for this concept. I have just translated it to English:

> - They created a competition for picking the lowest bid for the project.

Does it make sense to you? If not, what shall I say here?

Answer (score 2):

They

- put the project up for, *or*
- put the project out for, *or*
- solicited, *or*
- invited                     ***competitive bids***.

Comment: Do you mean: "puts the project up for competitive bids" or "puts the project out for competitive bids" or "solicits competitive bids"... @StoneyB?

Comment: Could you possibly use these structures in my sentence?

Answer (score 0):

What you have written makes sense, but there are specific terms for this activity, including "competitive tender", or "competitive bidding".

So: "They set up a competitive tender process to attract the lowest bid for the project."

If you are actually contemplating such a process, please be aware that it has its pitfalls!